# Specify via a flag during compilation with `pdflatex` that some commands are considered/ignored?

Tags: pdftex, margins, parameters

How can I create a flag, which allows to specify during compilation with `pdflatex` that some commands are considered/ignored?

Background: I want to create marginal notes with `\marginpar{...}` but they are just for my personal notes. Therefore, I look for a solution, where I can use one single tex-file with the `\marginpar{...}` commands inside, but I can create an output file with the marginal notes visible and one without the marginal notes visible. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that **all** margin par should be dropped in a certain mode, one can use a `\newif\ifdropmarginpar` and set it to true and redefine `\marginpar` to do nothing then!

```
\documentclass{article}



\newif\ifdropmarginpar
\dropmarginparfalse 
\dropmarginpartrue % Drop the marginpar

\ifdropmarginpar
\renewcommand{\marginpar}[2][]{%
}%
\fi

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\marginpar{Now you see it}

\end{document}
```